# .NET Core DI - Supplying null reference for required but unused class instance

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a few web projects and a standalone desktop app which leverage the same common libraries. When debugging the standalone desktop app to see why it isn't running, it feels like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack when trying to find out which unused service is required simply because it's in the constructor of a class that I do use. I've identified several classes which are used in most scenarios but not required in this one project.

I know that I can create constructors in those classes which do not require all of the services, but is there a way to add a null singleton to be used whenever DI detects that a class is needed for a constructor and I know that this class will never actually be used within the context of one of my projects? If so, is this an anti-pattern that I should avoid?

Comment: Why dont you just register the problem class in your services configuration?

Comment: I have already done so after looking through which unused class requires another unused class that requires another unused class. I am asking if it is possible for me to simply nullify any of these if I know a particular app is only going to waste resources by injecting services which it will never use.

Comment: If you’ve got redundant dependencies in your classes, why are the dependencies? Sounds like a code smell in those other classes to me.. I doubt very much that you’ll be able to register nulls like you want - it doesnt really work that way..

Comment: As I mentioned, they are useful in the vast majority of the apps which use this library. There is a single app which benefits from these existing classes but does not need to load up classes which it does not use at all. I can create nullable constructors for every one of these classes, but that takes time and seemed more tedious than nullifying the classes in the DI registration for this particular project.